# Concatenating 2 strings in a partial for a class style

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, string, concatenation, string-concatenation, partials

Ok so I am banging my head against the desk on something super simple I should be able to do and cant... I am trying to concatenate 2 strings, So I can have a dynamic class for a partial based on which page it is being rendered in.

The problem is the variable I am passing in is a string

```
 <%= render partial: "layouts/image_8_grid", 
 :locals=>{ :image_container => "small_image_container" }  %>
```

then inside the partial I am trying to do

```
class=<%= "#{image_container} grid_3" %>
```

but since container is "small_image_container" it is making the style go

```
class="image_container" grid_3=""
```

It doesn't look like there is any ruby method to concatenate strings... which is retarded. Am I missing something really obvious or am I going to have to make a custom method for something that is available in pretty much every other language?

Any insight would be appreciated, I am getting a little frustrated with not being able to find a method for something that seems like basic functionality that I have had in every other language I have worked with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to cat the string

```
class="<%= image_container %> grid_3"
```

Comment: Your right, both work but I will accept your answer. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 1):

So I just figured out that

```
class="<%= "#{image_container} grid_3" %>"
```

Works... Seems pretty backhanded but if it works it works I guess...